# AWK / String manipulation: How to pull strings out from a column and compare it with a number before printing the row

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, string

I have a list of data in a table. By using awk to pull out column 5, i was able to differentiate the data amongst the rows. If the `entry at column 5` is `more than 4`, the `row should be printed`.

However, there is one entry that comes in the form of a string that cannot be directly compared to a number, before deciding whether it should be printed or not. That entry has a parenthesis around the number that should be compared.

Here is the example of the column 5:

```
on
%)
%
replica
(

0
(100.0    <= this one
0.0
10.8
13.8
12.0
16.3
13.2
12.1
11.4
10.4
0.0
devices:
```

From the exmaple above, i am suppose to print rows 8 and 10 to 17 of the table.

I will provide a example table(file.txt):

```
1        0          0        0          on
2        0          0        0          %)
3        0          0        0          %
4        0          0        0          replica
5        0          0        0          (
6        0          0        0          
7        0          0        0          0
8        0          0        0          (100.0
9        0          0        0          0.0
1        0          0        0          10.8
1        1          0        0          13.8
1        2          0        0          12.0
1        3          0        0          16.3
1        4          0        0          13.2
1        5          0        0          12.1
1        6          0        0          11.4
1        7          0        0          10.4
1        8          0        0          0.0
1        9          0        0          devices:
```

My attempt:

```
awk '{if (($5>=4)) print;
else
    NUMBER=($5 | grep -o -E '[0-9]+');
    if (($NUMBER>=4)) print' file.txt
```

Error:

```
awk: syntax error near line 2
awk: illegal statement near line 2
awk: syntax error near line 3
awk: illegal statement near line 3
```

Comment: I may not have the gsub command in my system

Answer (score 1):

You could strip off the non-numeric characters before comparing:

```
$ awk '{x=$5; gsub(/[^0-9.]/,"",x);} x+0>=4' file.txt
8        0          0        0          (100.0
1        0          0        0          10.8
1        1          0        0          13.8
1        2          0        0          12.0
1        3          0        0          16.3
1        4          0        0          13.2
1        5          0        0          12.1
1        6          0        0          11.4
1        7          0        0          10.4
```

Comment: hmm, what if i have other conditions such as print when $1=="PM"? can i do this: awk '{if (($1=="PM")) print; x=$5; gsub(/[^0-9.]/,"",x);} x+0>=4' file.txt I received a syntax error

Comment: Yes that should work - although it would be more vernacular to add it as a *rule* like `x+0>=4 || $1=="PM"` (if a rule evaluates TRUE, the default action is `print`)

Comment: for some reason, the line of code you provided is giving me syntax errors. I am thinking perhaps i do not have the gsub command. May i ask what other commands can i explore? I tried {$5|egrep -v '(' }, but doesn't work

Comment: it works now! I just had to use gawk instead of awk for the gsub to work. Thank you for your help

Comment: @tthhss out of interest, what `awk` do you have? I tested the above with both `gawk` and `mawk` before posting